# JavaFX TreeView of multiple object types? (and more)

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, treeview

I currently have the following object data structure:

**Item**

- String name
- ArrayList of information

**Character**

- String name
- Collection of **Item**

**Account**

- String name
- Collection of **Character** (up to 8 max)

I want to make a TreeView that looks like the following:

```
Root(invisible)
======Jake(Account)
============JakesChar(Character)
==================Amazing Sword(Item)
==================Broken Bow(Item)
==================Junk Metal(Item)
======Mark(Account)
============myChar(Character)
==================Godly Axe(Item)
======FreshAcc(Account)
======MarksAltAcc(Account)
============IllLvlThisIPromise(Character)
======Jeffrey(Account)
============Jeff(Character)
==================Super Gun(Item)
==================Better Super Gun(Item)
==================Super Gun Scope(Item)
```

I made all those names up and such, obviously the real implementation would be a lot more complex. How can this be done? The TreeItem requires each TreeItem to be the same type as its' parent.

The ONLY solution I have is to do the following:

```
public class ObjectPointer
{
    Object pointer;
    String name;
}
```

My TreeView would be of type `ObjectPointer` and on each row I would cast the `ObjectPointer` to `Account`, `Character,` or `Item`. This is AWFUL but I think it would work.

**Sub Questions:**

- How do I get `TreeItem`(s) to detect `setOnMouseHover` events?
- How do I get `TreeItem`(s) to not use the `toString` method of their type and instead a custom way of displaying the `String` property that they need?
- How do I get the `TreeItem`(s) to display colored text in the GUI instead of plain text?

Thank you!

Comment: The main question is pretty difficult to do nicely. Your other questions (you should really post separate questions separately, not bundle multiple questions into one) are all answered by "use a `cellFactory` on the `TreeView‘". If I have time later I'll see if I can answer the main question.

Comment: You may think about create an Interface (like `Displayable`) and have all your classes Chararacter, Item, Account and other implementing it. This way, you can create a TreeView<Displayable>, but this can become ugly depending on the complexity of your app. Seeing the architecture of what you want to display, an other solution could be to have an XML (or JSON or else) converter that convert your model classes. Then you would only have to parse the XML data to display it to the user. It seems like a good way to separate model and display logics imo.

Comment: At some point it gets ugly no matter what you do, because the `TreeView` is homogeneous. Having all the objects implement an interface helps a bit.

Comment: So actually, I take the part about being ugly back. Since all the classes in the model are pretty similar, factoring out a (generic) superclass and using that as the type for the tree (essentially what @Kwoinkwoin suggests) makes this pretty nice. You might have to get your hands dirty with some type testing in the cell implementation, depending exactly what you want to do.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you look at your model and think generically, all the classes have a degree of similarity, which you could factor out into a superclass:

```
package model;

import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;

public abstract class GameObject<T extends GameObject<?>> {


    public GameObject(String name) {
        setName(name);
    }

    private final StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty();

    public final StringProperty nameProperty() {
        return this.name;
    }


    public final String getName() {
        return this.nameProperty().get();
    }


    public final void setName(final String name) {
        this.nameProperty().set(name);
    }

    private final ObservableList<T> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    public ObservableList<T> getItems() {
        return items ;
    }

    public abstract void createAndAddChild(String name);
}
```

The type parameter `T` here represents the type of "child" objects. So your `Account` class (whose child type is `GameCharacter` - don't name classes the same as anything in `java.lang`, btw...) looks like

```
package model;

public class Account extends GameObject<GameCharacter> {

    public Account(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    @Override
    public void createAndAddChild(String name) {
        getItems().add(new GameCharacter(name));
    }

}
```

and similarly all the way down the hierarchy. I'd define an `Information` class (even though it just has a name) to make everything fit the structure, so:

```
package model;

public class Item extends GameObject<Information> {

    public Item(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    @Override
    public void createAndAddChild(String name) {
        getItems().add(new Information(name));
    }

}
```

and, since `Information` has no children, its child list is just an empty list:

```
package model;

import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;

public class Information extends GameObject<GameObject<?>> {

    public Information(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    @Override
    public ObservableList<GameObject<?>> getItems() {
        return FXCollections.emptyObservableList();
    }

    @Override
    public void createAndAddChild(String name) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Information has no child items");
    }

}
```

Now every item in your tree is a `GameObject<?>`, so you can basically build a `TreeView<GameObject<?>>`. The tricky part is that your tree items need to reflect the structure already built in the model. Since you have observable lists there, you can do this with listeners on the lists.

You can use a cell factory on the tree to customize the appearance of the cells displaying the `TreeItem`s. If you want a different appearance for each type of item, I'd recommend defining the styles in an external CSS class, and setting a [CSS `PseudoClass`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/css/PseudoClass.html) on the cell corresponding to the type of item. If you use some naming convention (I have that the pseudo-class name is the lower case version of the class name), it can be quite slick to do that. Here's a fairly simple example:

```
package ui;

import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener.Change;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.css.PseudoClass;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeView;
import model.Account;
import model.GameCharacter;
import model.GameObject;
import model.Information;
import model.Item; 

public class Tree {

    private final TreeView<GameObject<?>> treeView ;

    private final List<Class<? extends GameObject<?>>> itemTypes = Arrays.asList(
         Account.class, GameCharacter.class, Item.class, Information.class
    );

    public Tree(ObservableList<Account> accounts) {
        treeView = new TreeView<>();

        GameObject<?> root = new GameObject<Account>("") {

            @Override
            public ObservableList<Account> getItems() {
                return accounts ;
            }

            @Override
            public void createAndAddChild(String name) {
                getItems().add(new Account(name));
            }

        };

        TreeItem<GameObject<?>> treeRoot = createItem(root);

        treeView.setRoot(treeRoot);
        treeView.setShowRoot(false);

        treeView.setCellFactory(tv -> {

            TreeCell<GameObject<?>> cell = new TreeCell<GameObject<?>>() {

                @Override
                protected void updateItem(GameObject<?> item, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);
                    textProperty().unbind();
                    if (empty) {
                        setText(null);
                        itemTypes.stream().map(Tree.this::asPseudoClass)
                            .forEach(pc -> pseudoClassStateChanged(pc, false));
                    } else {
                        textProperty().bind(item.nameProperty());
                        PseudoClass itemPC = asPseudoClass(item.getClass());
                        itemTypes.stream().map(Tree.this::asPseudoClass)
                            .forEach(pc -> pseudoClassStateChanged(pc, itemPC.equals(pc)));
                    }
                }
            };

            cell.hoverProperty().addListener((obs, wasHovered, isNowHovered) -> {
                if (isNowHovered && (! cell.isEmpty())) {
                    System.out.println("Mouse hover on "+cell.getItem().getName());
                }
            });

            return cell ;
        }
    }

    public TreeView<GameObject<?>> getTreeView() {
        return treeView ;
    }

    private TreeItem<GameObject<?>> createItem(GameObject<?> object) {

        // create tree item with children from game object's list:

        TreeItem<GameObject<?>> item = new TreeItem<>(object);
        item.setExpanded(true);
        item.getChildren().addAll(object.getItems().stream().map(this::createItem).collect(toList()));

        // update tree item's children list if game object's list changes:

        object.getItems().addListener((Change<? extends GameObject<?>> c) -> {
            while (c.next()) {
                if (c.wasAdded()) {
                    item.getChildren().addAll(c.getAddedSubList().stream().map(this::createItem).collect(toList()));
                }
                if (c.wasRemoved()) {
                    item.getChildren().removeIf(treeItem -> c.getRemoved().contains(treeItem.getValue()));
                }
            }
        });

        return item ;
    }

    private PseudoClass asPseudoClass(Class<?> clz) {
        return PseudoClass.getPseudoClass(clz.getSimpleName().toLowerCase());
    }

}
```

Quick test, which works, but note you probably need to test more of the functionality:

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import model.Account;
import model.GameCharacter;
import model.GameObject;
import model.Information;
import model.Item;
import ui.Tree;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Tree tree = new Tree(createAccounts());
        TreeView<GameObject<?>> treeView = tree.getTreeView();

        TextField addField = new TextField();
        Button addButton = new Button("Add");
        EventHandler<ActionEvent> addHandler = e -> {
            TreeItem<GameObject<?>> selected = treeView
                .getSelectionModel()
                .getSelectedItem();
            if (selected != null) {
                selected.getValue().createAndAddChild(addField.getText());
                addField.clear();
            }
        };
        addField.setOnAction(addHandler);
        addButton.setOnAction(addHandler);
        addButton.disableProperty().bind(Bindings.createBooleanBinding(() -> {
            TreeItem<GameObject<?>> selected = treeView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem() ;
            return selected == null || selected.getValue() instanceof Information ;
        }, treeView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty()));

        Button deleteButton = new Button("Delete");
        deleteButton.setOnAction(e -> {
            TreeItem<GameObject<?>> selected = treeView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem() ;
            TreeItem<GameObject<?>> parent = selected.getParent() ;
            parent.getValue().getItems().remove(selected.getValue());
        });
        deleteButton.disableProperty().bind(treeView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().isNull());

        HBox controls = new HBox(5, addField, addButton, deleteButton);
        controls.setPadding(new Insets(5));
        controls.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(treeView);
        root.setBottom(controls);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 600);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("/ui/style/style.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);

        primaryStage.show();
    }   

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    private ObservableList<Account> createAccounts() {
        Account jake = new Account("Jake");
        Account mark = new Account("Mark");
        Account freshAcc = new Account("Fresh Account");
        Account marksAltAcc = new Account("Mark's alternative account");
        Account jeffrey = new Account("Jeffrey");

        GameCharacter jakesChar = new GameCharacter("Jakes character");
        Item amazingSword = new Item("Amazing Sword");
        Item brokenBow = new Item("Broken Bow");
        Item junkMetal = new Item("Junk Metal");

        GameCharacter myChar = new GameCharacter("Me");
        Item godlyAxe = new Item("Godly Axe");

        GameCharacter level = new GameCharacter("I'll level this I promise");

        GameCharacter jeff = new GameCharacter("Jeff");
        Item superGun = new Item("Super Gun");
        Item superGunScope = new Item("Super Gun Scope");

        jake.getItems().add(jakesChar);
        mark.getItems().add(myChar);
        marksAltAcc.getItems().add(level);
        jeffrey.getItems().add(jeff);

        jakesChar.getItems().addAll(amazingSword, brokenBow, junkMetal);
        myChar.getItems().add(godlyAxe);
        jeff.getItems().addAll(superGun, superGunScope);

        return FXCollections.observableArrayList(jake, mark, freshAcc, marksAltAcc, jeffrey);

    }

}
```

and the CSS as an example:

```
.tree-cell, .tree-cell:hover:empty {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-background ;
    -fx-background: -fx-control-inner-background ;
}

.tree-cell:hover {
    -fx-background-color: crimson, -fx-background ;
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 1;
}

.tree-cell:account {
    -fx-background: lightsalmon ;
}
.tree-cell:gamecharacter {
    -fx-background: bisque ;
}
.tree-cell:item {
    -fx-background: antiquewhite ;
}

.tree-cell:selected {
    -fx-background: crimson ;
}
```

Comment: Added a related, but complete (and more general) example on [github](https://github.com/james-d/heterogeneous-tree-example)

Comment: I gotta say, the effort you put into your posts here are truly commendable. Thank you for going into so much detail. One thing that I'm kind of nervous about here is changing the way my project sees the `Account`, `GameCharacter`, or `Item` classes JUST for the purpose of `TreeView`. Would doing `TreeView<Object> myTree = new TreeView<>();` and then casting it to `Account`, `GameCharacter`, or `Item` when I need to, be a bad idea? The `Interface` idea with one field is also an interesting one. I'm just kind of scared of doing the Inheritance idea because of how far I am into my project.

Comment: Also is there no non-homogeneous `TreeView`? I'm surprised no one has attempted to make one yet. I'm a bit confused on why a `TreeView` even NEEDS to be homogeneous. It'd be like... `GridPane` having to be homogeneous. Imagine `GridPane` having to have the same type of `Node` in each slot of its' grid. It would be pointless. Why does `TreeView` have to be this way?

Comment: Your reluctance to use inheritance is well-founded. Testing for types and casting is also a bit of a code-smell... unfortunately the fact that `TreeView` uses a single type throughout effectively forces you to choose between one of those two evils. Have a look at the slightly more general version of this I put on [github](https://github.com/james-d/heterogeneous-tree-example): the `ModelTree` there makes no assumptions about the inheritance hierarchy. You can basically encapsulate the type testing in the functions you pass into the `ModelTree`.

Comment: Well, you misunderstand "homogeneous" a bit there. `GridPane` is homogeneous: every child has the same type: `Node`. Of course, you can pass in any node you like (Liskov substitution principal), but if you wanted to iterate through the `getChildren()` list and do something specific to the type of nodes you had passed in, you would essentially be in the same situation. It probably would have been possible to define `TreeItem<T,C>` with `T getValue()` and `ObservableList<C> getChildren()`, but it would get *ver* complex to use and probably prohibit inexperienced programmers from using it.

Comment: I'll take a look at the GitHub repo right away. Also about the `.setOnHover()` with the `CellFactory()`, here's what I have right now when I hover over a given item: http://i.imgur.com/p2xVtyO.png . It looks nice so I'd really want to use it in the `TreeView`. In your `treeView.setCellFactory` line, I see that this is called on `TreeView` and not `TreeItem`. This makes it a lot harder than I thought since I have to define a `CellFactory` for the ENTIRE `TreeView` and not just a `TreeItem`. I can see why your inheritance idea with a parameter is helpful in this regard.

Comment: And, similarly, it would have been possible to define `GridPane` as a `GridPane<N extends Node>` with a `ObservableList<N> getChildren()`, but again the flexibility-complexity trade off is probably not worth it (and would reduce the target audience for the whole toolkit).

Comment: Define `setOnHover` on the **`TreeCell`s** you create (or, if possible, use CSS for the hover effects). Added example.

Comment: Hmmm so I'm still a bit confused on the `TreeCell` thing. Right now I'm trying a few ideas, `Object` being the first. I have `@Override public TreeCell<Object> call(TreeView<Object> arg0)`. Now I need to `return` a `TreeCell<Object>`. Here's where it gets confusing to me. I need to know what is inside of this `TreeCell`. If the user is over an `Item`, then I want my `TreeCell` to have a `setOnMouseHover` effect. I also needs to know exactly what type of `Item` it is dealing with. If I somehow had `TreeItem`, THEN I can do `.getValue()` and be great, but instead I just have a `TreeView` object.

Comment: Just call [`getItem()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Cell.html#getItem--) or [`getTreeItem()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TreeCell.html#getTreeItem--) as needed... I added an example of implementing hover in the answer.

Comment: The `getTreeItem()` of the `TreeView` class requires a row or column input which I can't view from `treeView.setCellFactory(new Callback<TreeView<Object>, TreeCell<Object>>()`

Comment: Dude, ***`TreeCell`*** has `getTreeItem()` and `getItem()` methods (did you follow the links?) Again, see the example code in my `TreeCell` implementation above.

Comment: I'm sorry, this whole `cellFactory()` stuff is extremely confusing to me. I read through most of your code but keep in mind I'm more of a intermediate JavaFX learner and the content above is something I'd say is pretty advanced. Right now I made a class which `extends TreeCell<MyInterface>` (`MyInterface` being a way for me to bypass the `Object` thing) but I'm having trouble with setting the `Graphic` property. I read in the API that I can do `graphicProperty.bind(Observable value)` which can prevent me having to do the painful `update()` stuff. But I don't know how to convert `Label` to `OV`

Comment: This is probably well away from your original question now (your original question was a design question; this is a more basic "how does tree view work" question). Cells in general are documented [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Cell.html).

Comment: How can `object.getItems().stream().map(this::createItem)` in your `createItem` method work? I get a `LambdaConversionException`. The reason is, the method `createItem` requires a `GameObject<?>`. However, the `object` parameter's `getItems` method returns `Object`, not `GameObject<?>`.

Comment: It compiles and runs fine for me (JDK1.8.0_71). `GameObject` is defined as `GameObject<T extends GameObject<?>>`, so whatever `T` is, it must be a subclass of `GameObject<?>`. `getItems()` returns an `ObservableList<T>`, so effectively you have `ObservableList<? extends GameObject<?>>`, calling `stream()` gives a `Stream<? extends GameObject<?>>` and so each element of the stream is an instance of an unknown subclass of `GameObject<?>`. That guarantees that element can be passed to the `createItem()` method.

Comment: I'm using 1.8.0_77. It compiles fine, but doesn't run. When I explicitly cast the stream to a `Stream<? extends GameObject<?>` it works indeed. This is possible without any type conversion warnings.

Comment: That seems strange; I find it hard to understand how that level of typing is even retained at runtime. What happens if you explicitly assign variables at each step (i.e. `ObservableList<? extends GameObject<?>> items = object.getItems();`, `Stream<? extends GameObject<?>> itemStream = items.steam();`, `Stream<TreeItem<GameObject<?>>> treeItemStream = itemStream.map(this::createItem);`, `List<TreeItem<GameObject<?>>> treeItemList = treeItemStream.collect(Collectors.toList());`?

Comment: That works as well. When I let Eclipse extract the local variable, it would choose `Stream<Object>` for `getItems` by itself, not `Stream<? extends GameObject<?>>`. As I mentioned, explicitly specifying `Stream<? extends GameObject<?>>` as the declaration type works without compile and runtime errors. Maybe it's an Eclipse bug?