# JavaFX TreeView with heterogeneous multiple type nodes

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, treeview

What I must do, if I want make "ultra-heterogeneous" tree-view, where I can plaсe any set of different objects in any node of tree?
In [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35009982/javafx-treeview-of-multiple-object-types-and-more) contains some version of release such task, but then we have "heterogeneous" on branch of tree, but must have "homogeneous" on each level.
In really I make navigation tree for object browser with complex (but definite) structure of "node-objects type" relations, where it is some skeleton objects, always presented in tree (static information etc), and some sets of var objects, queried from database (reports, documents etc).
For example, first level may contain node for: customer info (with specific sublevels), primery documents (with sublevels for different types) and created documents (various types):

```
Customer(root)
==CustomerInfo
====CustomerInfoType1
====...
====CustomerInfoTypeN    
==PrimeryReports
====PrimeryReportType1
======PrimeryReportType1Date1
======...
======PrimeryReportType1DateM
====PrimeryReportType2
======PrimeryReportType2Date1
======...
======PrimeryReportType2DateM
==ResultDocuments
====ResultDocumentType1
====...
====ResultDocumentTypeK
```

The tree node of different type contains (pointer to) specific object and related display form (FXML link) to display object content.
What kind of structure I can/ must use?

Comment: Ultimately, a `TreeView` is homogeneous. If there is no commonality at all between the objects represented in the `TreeView`, you are reduced to using a `TreeView<Object>` and simply casting the objects based on what you know about their type from your business logic.

Comment: don't quite see why your problem should be different from the one in the referenced question ... from the perspective of the two possible (and suboptimal) solutions it looks the same to me .. tempted to close as duplicate

Comment: Actually, the only difference I see between this and the question you linked is that you may need a degree of abstraction on some of the levels. E.g. for the level immediately below the root `abstract class CustomerData` and `class CustomerInfo extends CustomerData`, `class PrimaryReports extends CustomerData` etc. Even that may not really be necessary.